# Specific interpolation method in Pandas/Scipy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

first create the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
data = pd.DataFrame({'time':np.arange(10)})
data['sin_of_the_times']= np.sin(data.time)
newdata = pd.DataFrame({'time': np.linspace(0,10,15)})
newdata['sin_of_the_times'] = np.NAN
data['interpolated']=False
newdata['interpolated']= True
ultimatedata = pd.concat([data, newdata])
ultimatedata.sort_values('time', inplace=True)
```

Which gives you this:

```
    time    sin_of_the_times    interpolated
0   0.000000    0.000000    False
0   0.000000    NaN         True
1   0.714286    NaN         True
1   1.000000    0.841471    False
2   1.428571    NaN         True
2   2.000000    0.909297    False
...
```

**Without making a new function** is there an interpolation method already existing in Python that will take:

- the first NaN and say time=0.0 is 0% the way from time=0 and time=1.0 therefore is 0% of the way between 0 and .8 thus will be 0.0.
- the 2nd NaN will be 7/10th's (ish) the way between 0 and 1 therefore 7/10ths the way from 0 to 0.841471 so it will be .5890297
- the third NaN will be 4/10ths (ish) the way between 1 and 2 therefore also 4/10ths the way from 0.841471 and 0.909297

Is there a name for this type of interpolation method? (in this case it's upsample'ing) the interpolation methods seem to be based on one column only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still want to do a linear interpolation; you just want to specify that the distance between the points depends on `time` instead of assuming they are evenly spaced. So first set the index to `time` then use `interpolate`

```
df = df.set_index('time')
df.sin_of_the_times.interpolate(method='index')
```

#### Output:

```
time
0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000
0.714286    0.601051
1.000000    0.841471
1.428571    0.870539
2.000000    0.909297
Name: sin_of_the_times, dtype: float64
```

---

This is what I started from: `df`

```
       time  sin_of_the_times
0  0.000000          0.000000
0  0.000000               NaN
1  0.714286               NaN
1  1.000000          0.841471
2  1.428571               NaN
2  2.000000          0.909297
```

Answer (score 3):

Build for speed `interp` from `numpy`

```
np.interp(df['time'].values,
          df.dropna()['time'].values,
          df.dropna()['sin_of_the_times'].values)
Out[783]: 
array([0.        , 0.        , 0.60105095, 0.841471  , 0.87053926,
       0.909297  ])


#df['sin_of_the_times']= np.interp(df['time'].values,
#                           df.dropna()['time'].values,
#                            df.dropna()['sin_of_the_times'].values)
```